# Forcing tuples within tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got a python function that should loop through a tuple of coordinates and print their contents:

```
def do(coordList):
    for element in coordList:
        print element
y=((5,5),(4,4))
x=((5,5))
```

When y is run through the function, it outputs (5,5) and (4,4), the desired result. However, running x through the function outputs 5 and 5.

Is there a way to force x to be defined as a tuple within a tuple, and if not, what is the easiest way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a trailing comma for singleton tuples.

```
x = ((5, 5),)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
x=((5,5),)
```

(*x*) is an expression (*x*,) is a singleton tuple.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old and infuriating quirk of python syntax. You have to include a trailing comma to make Python see a tuple:

```
x = ((5,5),)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a comma after your first tuple. 
`((5,5),)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a comma:

```
x=((5,5),)
```